# Correct auxiliary verb form

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs

What would be the right form of the auxiliary verb here and why?

> choosing suitable tools **are** vital

or

> choosing suitable tools **is** vital

Comment: (**The act** of) choosing suitable tools **is** vital.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the auxiliary verb is describing the first verb (present-participle) "Choosing", and it is **singular**, so "**is**" would be used.

Comment: Thanks Bella.., You are Awesome...!

Comment: @Prasanth You're welcome! If the answer satisfies your question, please approve it (by clicking that tick mark on the left of the question)